# How should we close medical questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Exactly how should we close questions which ask about medical issues that cannot be answered except by being in presence of a doctor who has the knowledge about that person's issue/condition/history like [this one](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14799/is-fasting-going-to-effect-my-blood-pressure-problem)?

I think off-topic, and if everyone agrees, do we need to make an off-topic reason for specifically these types of questions? Since we are going into Ramadan, and this site has a traffic site in this month and I have noticed we get these types of questions more.

Comment: If this is the 1st question that asks about medical issues then I suggest we wait a little bit more before creating a new off-topic reason. That being said, you might want to check this [related discussion on Meta.Fitness.SE](http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/70/medical-questions)

Comment: But yeah. They have this under thier off-topic reason: "*Questions on general health and medical advice are off-topic here; you should contact a qualified medical professional instead*"